# Weird hyphenation in headers on Android

Tags: android, css, web

No idea why this is happening, and I only have one Android device to test on, so not sure if it's across the board or only on this Asus EEEPad thing.

Screenshot (sorry, it's not a connected device): http://imgur.com/iz3R1UH

Live version, if someone with an Android device wouldn't mind testing for me: http://ftempdecrypto.com/get-help/

Any ideas?  I set hyphens to none, then manual, with no luck.

Comment: What does it look like in an emulator?

Comment: It turns out it was a plugin called WP-Typography, which did allow for hyphenation.  Disabling it fixed the problem.  Weird though, that I explicitly tried to disable hyphens for those headings.

Comment: @Mike, you should clarify the question, post an answer, and self-accept it, if you have found a solution. Otherwise the question will not be of use to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

There was an old plugin called "WP-Typography" that was supposed to handle things like hyphenation and widows, etc.

Disabling this abandoned plugin immediately fixed the problem.